# por que no se ve el toolbar cuando uso inflate()

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

estoy tratando de colocar un menu en un toolbar de mi aplicación android pero ya intente de varias maneras sin éxito (es frustrante)

este es el menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_game"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"
        android:title="nuevo game" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:title="ayuda" />
</menu>
```

este es el xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PlayGame" >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:backgroundTint="#311B92"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

y este es el codigo del activity, intente pasarle menuInflater de forma directa y no funciono, tambien deje de agregar sel setactionbar en el oncreate y tampoco funciono, nose que mas hacer para que se muestre el menu en el tolbar que agregue en el xml?

```
package com.example.game

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.widget.Toolbar

class PlayGame : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setActionBar(toolbar)
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        return true
    }
}
```

**Solución:**

me voy auto responder a la consulta (agradeciendo a las amables respuestas); para solucionar esto seguí la documentación de Android.

1. en el manifest y aplicación agrega lo siguiente para asignar un thema no action

- android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

2. luego en el xml de la activity agrega su toolbar
3. posteriormente, en el metodo oncreate se agrega lo siguiente para llamar al tolbar

- setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

4. finalmente con el metodo oncreateoptionmenu se agrega el menu en el toolbar

saludos.

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu()` ya es obsoleto. Considera usar `MenuProvider` y `onCreateMenu`. Lee [este artículo](https://medium.com/tech-takeaways/how-to-migrate-the-deprecated-oncreateoptionsmenu-b59635d9fe10) y revisa el ejemplo en el apartado **Adding a MenuProvider from an Activity**. Puedes revisar también el código de la App modelo de Android en su [repositorio de Github](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/GardenActivity.kt). En conclusión, evita usar `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: Otros que están obsoletos, por si piensas usarlos, son `onOptionsItemSelected()`, en su lugar se usa `onMenuItemSelected()` y `setHasOptionsMenu()` que ya no es necesario, como podrás ver en los ejemplos antes mencionados. Para más ejemplos de código, en Activity y en Fragment, puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71965674/5587982).

Answer (score 1):

Asegurate que en tu archivo xml Theme tengas el estilo definido asi

```
<style name="Theme.ReproducThor" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```